# IsMouseOver is false when mouse is over child elements in custom WPF button template

Tags: wpf, .net-4.5

I'm trying to create a straight-forward, colored button in WPF that changes colors when the mouse is over and again when the button is pressed. I've been working in web projects lately and it's insane how much more complicated styling WPF is vs. HTML.

Commentary aside, although the [MS documentation on UIElement.IsMouseOver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ismouseover(v=vs.110).aspx) states that it includes child elements, I'm experiencing the opposite. My trigger changes the color when my pointer is right over the border of the button, but as soon as it moves a few pixels farther inward, it changes back. Using Snoop, as I move the pointer pixel by pixel toward the center of the button, I can see that IsMouseOver is true for the border, then for the ContentPresenter, then for the inner TextBlock, but they are mutually exclusive. When IsMouseOver is true for a child element, it's false for the parents. I've seen lots of examples using the same approach as mine, but it's not working. I've gone through quite a few edits so maybe I have some erroneous syntax. How do I make the trigger apply when the mouse is anywhere within the button.

Here is my code. I define the brushes as resources of the button, override the default control template replacing the Chrome border with a regular Border, and then replace the brushes in Style Triggers.

```
<Grid Name="grdResults" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0" Visibility="Visible">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        ...
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Content="X" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,3,0" Padding="5,1">
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
                <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="WhiteSmoke" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="BorderBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF9B9B9B" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF666666" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA21E00" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF550000" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MouseOverBackgroundBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFB63200" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF681800" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MouseDownBorderBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF666666" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF9B9B9B" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MouseDownBackgroundBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF550000" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA21E00" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ForegroundBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFB9B9B9" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MouseDownForegroundBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFB9B9B9" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Resources>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="4" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <ContentPresenter Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MouseOverBackgroundBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MouseDownBackgroundBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MouseDownBorderBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MouseDownForegroundBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
    <TextBlock Text="Posts Processed:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="13,0,0,0" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Name="tbPostsProcessed" Margin="3,0,13,0" Text="{Binding PostsProcessed}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

Edit:

I've also just discovered the MouseOver trigger seems to work everywhere to the right of the X (button content). Very strange. IsPressed also seems to only work on the same pixels that MouseOver works on.

Comment: I was, ironically, so focused on the Border, I didn't even notice that up there. However, I've set `Fill="Transparent"` on the ButtonFocusVisual Rectangle and am still getting the same behavior.

Comment: From your edit it seems that you have something over your `Button`. I've copied your `Style` to new app and it works fine over whole button

Comment: @dkozl You're correct...a transparent TextBlock, that I had previously set to align left was somehow set back to stretch and was covering it. I also tried it without a Fill on the rectangle and it still works. I'll update the sample code. Post as an answer and I'll mark it

Comment: Yes it will work without `Recangle.Fill`, I did not check whole template. As for an answer thanks but there is not much for a useful one here. If you feel it'll be beneficial for other SO users you can post one yourself otherwise you can delete question

Comment: Add a handler to your label/image/whatever that calls Mybase.OnMouseOver(e)